# .csv TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len() and averaging rows

Tags: python, list, csv, file, append

I have to create a module that reads in an RNA-seq counts table (counts_table.csv) line by line, computes the average number of counts across each gene_ID, and writes the original table contents, in addition to the average counts in a new column, to a new file. My code cannot contain any import statements. This is what I have so far for my function:

```
def count_average(input_file, output_file):
try:
    fin = open(input_file, "w")
    fout = open(output_file, 'w')
except:
    return -1 
with fin, fout:
    sums = []
    averages = []
    for i in range(len(fin)):
        sums.append(0)
        for n in range(len(fin[i])):
            sums[i] += fin[i][n]
            averages[i] += sums[i]/[n]
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line)
        fout.append(averages)
```

I know I am successfully opening the files and I can append all of the information of the infile to the outfile however I have two things I am stuck on.

1. I keep getting TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()
2. I am not sure if my code will properly append the averages and I don't know how to make a new average header on top of those

Ultimately I want the final result to look something like this:
[Input_to_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVpFv.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are opening the file in wrong way. Instead of writing this:

```
fin = open(input_file, "w")
```

Write this:

```
fin = open(input_file, "r")
```

Comment: I still get "TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()" when writing it like this

Answer (score 0):

would be much easier to provide a working example if you had posted your actual data.

The problem is this line:

```
for i in range(len(fin)):
```

and this line:

```
for n in range(len(fin[i])):
```

To iterate over every line/row in your file, use something like this instead:

```
for row in fin:
```

and then:

```
 for cell in row:
```

EDIT:
To still get an index use `for index, row in enumerate(fin):`

Comment: That fixed the len() error I am getting but now I have a new error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: You can use `for index, row in enumerate(fin):` to get an index.